# Convert a unicode string to a string

Tags: c++, string, class, unicode, typeconverter

I have created some C++ classes in C++ Builder. I am now using these in a VCL forms application. I have a function that loads a text file and takes a string as an argument.

I am using an openDialog control to browse to the file to then open it up.

My problem is this: The .filename property of the openFialog is in the form of UnicodeString and my function needs a std::string. How can I convert a unicode string to a std::string?

Here is my code:

```
OpenDialog1->Execute();
calCalendar.loadAppointmentsFromFile(OpenDialog1->FileName.t_str());
```

Here is the function definition:

```
void loadAppointmentsFromFile(const std::string& stringFilename);
```

I am getting the following error:

[BCC32 Error] Assessment2.cpp(39): E2342 Type mismatch in parameter 'stringFilename' (wanted 'const std::string &', got 'wchar_t *')

Can I please have some help to rectify this problem?

Comment: Are you talking about ICU? Then http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/converters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [UnicodeString::t_str](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__UnicodeString__t_str.html) to get a narrowed string. However, you should consider not mixing the two.

Another option is to convert to an `AnsiString` first:

```
AnsiString str = OpenDialog1->FileName;
std::string s(str.c_str());
loadAppointmentsFromFile(s);
```

Or

```
std::string s = OpenDialog1->FileName.t_str(); // TCHAR mapping set to char
loadAppointmentsFromFile(s);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am still having a problem with my code. I have added to my original post. Can you please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @user1690531: My link has the answer to your question, the TCHAR_mapping options is set to `wchar_t`, go to `Project->Options->Directories and Conditionals` and change it to `char`.

Comment: I have changed it to char. Yet am still getting the same error.

Comment: @user1690531: Okay, then try my second approach (although you really should just be using wide strings).

Comment: DO NOT USE `UnicodeString::t_str()`!!!  It is dangerous, as it alters the UnicodeString's internal data, which can have side-effects.  Plus, `t_str()` was removed in a later version of C++Builder anyway.  The correct solution to this problem is to assign the `UnicodeString` to an `AnsiString` and then use `AnsiString::c_str()`.